# Gem not found in Ruby cron job in RVM env

Tags: ruby, macos, cron, rvm, powerpc

I'm trying to run a simple ruby script on my old PPC machine running 10.5 in an RVM environment.

Searching on SO, I've followed the chosen answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680561/need-to-set-up-rvm-environment-prior-to-every-cron-job).

This is the line in cron as a result:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
00 * * * * BASH_ENV=~/.bash_profile && /bin/bash -c '~/deggy/onlineGW.rb'
```

This command runs fine in Bash at the root of the user sam.

Here's the salient part of my script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'nokogiri'
 ...
```

Here's the output of the error from cron:

```
 X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
 X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
 X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=sam>
 X-Cron-Env: <USER=sam>
 X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/sam>
 Date: Mon,  6 Jan 2014 03:15:00 -0600 (CST)
 /Users/sam/deggy/onlineGW.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
```

OK, since I'm running RVM I have set my default ruby to 1.9.3 and as I mentioned above, the command executes in Terminal but not in cron. Is there another environment in play?

So clearly, there's something I'm overlooking. Help me to see it, sam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I configured several different operating systems to work with a couple of CRON flavors and RVM.

I first tried [RVM's official](http://rvm.io/integration/cron) solution to the problem but didn't work under FreeBSD and Gentoo. I had to manually add all relevant paths as showed bellow but first type `crontab -e` in order to launch the crontab editor[1]:

```
# atmat's crontab configuration
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/home/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/atma/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/i486-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.5.3
RUBYLIB=/home/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1
GEM_HOME='/home/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0'
GEM_PATH='/home/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0:/home/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global'
RUBYOPT=rubygems

%nightly,mail(no) * 8-9 /home/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby  /usr/local/bin/morula -s username update
```

The above example is working under Gentoo GNU/Linux using [fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/) a more flexible, beautiful and powerful solution to standard cron, but will work with any cron.

[1] This command will open `crontab` with your default system editor.

Comment: One of the things that I've not read is WHERE the config for crontab is. Where would I update my configuration?

Comment: I believe the equivalent of your config lines are pasted at the top of the crontab. I get a little closer as my error returns `read_nonblock': Connection reset by
 peer.  Of course, in terminal using BASH_ENV=~/.bash_profile && /bin/bash -c '~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby ~/deggy/onlineGW.rb' works so it's not likely the remote server blocking it.

Comment: I added the requested info.

Comment: I was having a similar issue where a shell script (run from cron) was using ruby.  I had to do `export <VARIABLE>` for it to work, just in case others encounter the same.

Comment: @WayneWeibel What OS and Shell are you using?

Comment: @atomsx that was part of the problem actually, the shell for cron was not the same as the user (we think) and I tested on a Mac, but our servers are CentOS and Ubuntu with different ruby installs on top of the rvm shenanigans ... as you can tell it is a bit of a cluster-(you know)

Answer (score 31):

Or you can simply try

`rvm cron setup # let RVM do your cron settings`

which worked for me. via https://coderwall.com/p/vhv8aw

Comment: WARNING: this overwrites your existing crontab entries

Comment: This worked for me (finally!) but did NOT overwrite my existing crontab (rvm -v = 1.26.11)

Comment: Works. Did NOT overwrite my crontab entries!

Comment: I wish we could make it THE answer. It just quietly worked adding necessary ENV variables to the top of the cron.

Answer (score 0):

To load default RVM ruby environment for `cron` jobs, here is what I setup for user-mode RVM, assume the user is `ohho`, home folder is `/home/ohho`. To edit, enter `crontab -e` in command line:

```
MAILTO=""
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/home/ohho/.bash_profile
HOME=/home/ohho

* * * * * rails -v > /home/ohho/env.txt
```

The last line is for testing `rails` (if installed) can be invoked properly. You should also check whether `~/.bash_profile` loads the RVM environment (which is default for bash).

A detail explanation of `SHELL` and `BASH_ENV` can be found in [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788368/88597).