# Rails whenever not work with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rvm, whenever

I followed this issue https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/714
and set my `schedule.rb` like this.

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
set :output, {:error => '~/Desktop/z.error.log', :standard => '~/Desktop/z.standard.log'}

every 1.minute do
  runner 'Price.create'
end
```

Then I check my `crontab -l`, it showed the following command

```
PATH=/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails514/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/MyUserName/Desktop/my-project && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Price.create'\'' >> ~/Desktop/z.standard.log 2>> ~/Desktop/z.error.log'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/MyUserName/Desktop/my-project/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-01-30 02:13:32 +0800
```

It seems great and executable, however, I checked the error log and found the following errors.

bundler: failed to load command: bin/rails (bin/rails)

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find erubi-1.7.0 in any of the sources
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `materialize'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I felt a little bit confused and wondering why I could not load the right gem path.

**Environment:**

OSX: 10.13.2

Rails 5.1.4

Ruby 2.3.3

### Update

I found out that the error message from log stated that

```
/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'`,
```

However, I check my `crontab -l`, it clearly showed this setting

```
#sm start rvm
PATH="/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails514/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails514/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin"
GEM_HOME='/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails514'
GEM_PATH='/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails514:/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global'
MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3'
IRBRC='/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/.irbrc'
RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.3.3'
#sm end rvm
```

I am confused why it still get the wrong rvm version.
Did I miss something?

### Update 2

After I changed the default `gemset`, it works perfectly.

I used this command

```
rvm use 2.3.3@rails514 --default
```

But does anyone can tell me how to put the right path in `crontab` instead of setting rvm default?

Comment: What happens if you type `cd /Users/MyUserName/Desktop/my-project && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Price.create'\'' ` , which is what CRONTAB is running, at the command-line? Maybe that will help troubleshoot.

Comment: It works perfectly.

Comment: I found that the error message states that `/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails4271/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'`, and have updated my question!

Comment: So the command works from the command line but not via crontab, so you need to do some rvm/crontab troubleshooting. Maybe https://rvm.io/deployment/cron or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954298/gem-not-found-in-ruby-cron-job-in-rvm-env will be some help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run

```
rvm cron setup
```

Not sure if it fix the problem, but had a similar issue once, and worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: It helps me add something like `PATH`, `GEM_HOME`, `GEM_PATH` in crontab, but it doesn't change anything. I still got the same errors message.